# Xamarin.Android Jar Binding 'MyClass' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])'

Tags: java, c#, android, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

I am totally new to Xamarin.Android and C#. And I was trying to generate a .dll file by using Binding project to bind My Andorid project's Jar file for Xamarin.Android. In my code I do implement doInBackground method. So I am not sure what should be the solution? Because of copyright issues I can not post my entire code but following is the generalized implementation of doInBackground method:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<SomeObject> doInBackground(Void...params) {
    // doing some operation
}
```